# Scikit-image 64 bit instead of 32 bit in buildrozer

Tags: python, kivy, scikit-image

Hi I want to build a android application in kivy. in python code I use scikit-image. when I try to build the code using buildrozer I found that buildrozer use 64 bit instead of 32 bit. I actually don't know which program have error buildrozer, kivy, or scikit-image can anyone tell me how to solve the error

error below

`stderr: Traceback (most recent call last): [WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/anirban/Documents/softfarms/Scanner/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm eabi-v7a/build/python-installs/document_scanner/skimage/__init__.py", line 121, in <module> [WARNING] stderr: ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/user/0/com.document.scanner.document_scanner/files/a pp/_python_bundle/site-packages/skimage/_shared/geometry.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit`

Comment: What this really indicates is that it hasn't been compiled for android at all, it needs a python-for-android build recipe but isn't currently supported.

Comment: How to solve this ?

Comment: Write a python-for-android build recipe. This may be quite tricky and doesn't have a great deal of documentation.

Comment: Thanks but this will time consuming ...

Comment: Yes, realistically you may not be able to get scikit-image working on android within a kivy app.